# How can I produce high quality images of field ranges for training sets?

Tags: troubleshooting, focus, aperture-priority

I am an Agronomic researcher  assisting on a ML problem for identifying soy diseases. I would like to capture an image of a single range of soy (*roughly 1' wide by 5' long*) that is at least mostly in-focus (*but will also be divided into smaller images for ease of clarity*). Ideally experts will evaluate these fields, and their evaluation along with this image, will be passed along to train the algorithm.

I am using a Canon EOS 6D mark II for this project with an EF 24–105mm f/3.5–5.6 IS STM lens. I have tried taking some images in Av mode with a *narrow* aperture of up to f/22 which is the max it will let me do from an angle in front of the range. Only the top bit of the plants matters terribly much for this context. I have been using the autofocus option available, but centering the area in the middle of the top of the range. I have not tried editing shutter time yet, and I'm not really sure how to optimize.

Another question I have thought to ask:

Reducing the 1' width down to a 0-dimension for this figure, if the plants a roughly 2' tall, what angle must I be at to capture a clear image with what aperture and ISO options so that the tops (*or the top of the green rectangle in this question*) are mostly clearly visible?

*Any and all advice is extremely welcome! I'm a relatively novice photographer, but the outcomes of this are decently important and photo quality is the number one parameter holding us up right now.*

[image]

*Edit*

I was asked to post some of the photos we'd being using:

So here is with autofocus: ([link to full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngkum.jpg))

[image]

With narrowest aperture, f/22: ([link to full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQKpP.jpg))

[image]

Ideally we can get this clear enough that we can train both a ML algorithm on this AND have professionals rate it from photos alone.

Comment: Please post some of the photos, along with a description of what you'd like to improve about them. Also be aware that f/22 is the _narrowest_ aperture that your lens will do, not the widest.

Comment: "*with a wide aperture of up to f/22 which is the max*" FYI F22 is a narrow aperture, The higher the number the smaller the aperture. "*which is the max it will let me do from an angle in front of the range*" I do not understand how aperture is related to what angle you are shooting. ?

Comment: "*Reducing the 1' width down to a 0-dimension for this figure, if the plants a roughly 2' tall, what angle must I be at to capture a clear image with what aperture and ISO options so that the tops (or the top of the green rectangle in this question) are mostly clearly visible?*"   - The goal is to show a cross section of the tops of the plants to evaluate the health of the plants. ?  Is  The purpose of the angle is to show as much of the tops of the plants as possible (fill the frame)?

Comment: I'd lay out a rectangle of paper or carpet (or actual soybeans) and take some test images at various apertures. Take a look at them and see what works. The greater your viewpoint angle the less you'll need to stop down.

Comment: @AlaskaMan Yes, that is exactly the point to fill the frame with the x-section of the plants!

Comment: @Drew - The first photo is better but  not a great depth of field. The second look as if the plants moved in the wind and you had a slower shutter speed.   If the tops of the plants are the area of concern and study, and not the lower parts of the plant,  then changing the angle of camera so it is shooting more from above looking down will make it so the tops of the plants are all closer to the focal plane and thus you do not need such a large depth of field.

Comment: @Drew It looks like you're creating images to train a neural network? To avoid training the network on details that are irrelevant, consider providing images taken with a variety of devices and settings that it could realistically encounter. It's also not clear that the photos *need* to be in focus throughout the frame to determine plant health. For instance, color may be of greater relevance. You may also want to look into [NDVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_difference_vegetation_index), which uses a modified camera to evaluate plant health.

Comment: Why was that specific camera and lens chosen for your project? Cameras with smaller sensors and focal lengths would provide greater depth of field at any given aperture. Perhaps smart-phone images would be sufficient for your needs? An app that evaluates images taken on the phone itself would be more useful than one that requires the use of a full-frame camera.

Comment: you might consider a light field camera. the resolution isn't as high, but you can focus in post, which would let you get different distance plants in focus  in a composite image. A pinhole might be another option if it has enough detail: everything is in focus (or cynically in CoC blur the size of the pinhole) on a pinhole lens, no matter the distance.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, it sounds like what you want is a **Tilt/Shift Lens**.

This will allow you to adjust the focal plane to be more in line with your shot.

Some quick examples from the web:

[Marc Muench on Using a Tilt-Shift Lens](https://www.pictureline.com/blogs/archive/using-a-tilt-shift-lens-and-the-schleimplug-principle)

[image: Marc Muench on Using a Tilt-Shift Lens]

[Using Lens Tilt for Landscape Photography](https://www.australianlight.com.au/blog/post/using_lens_tilt_for_landscape_photography/)

[image: Using Lens Tilt for Landscape Photography]

Be aware that these lenses are not Cheap, as in around $2000 for a Canon Tilt/shift.

Comment: This is pretty good advice! I didn't know these existed! I'll definitely pass this along and see if it's in the budget.